# Ubuntu 15.04, Asus Flipbook TP500LN No Internet and touchpad did use NDISwrapper

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, touchpad, asus

So I installed Ubunutu 15.04 on my Asus Flipbook TP500LN, but I don't have acces to wi-fi (ethernet does work). Now I read about Ndiswrapper, I installed the program and used it to install my wi-fi driver, which I got from the official Asus website. It all went pretty well, but even though it says that the driver is installed and there is a yes I still don't have acces to wi-fi.

I also tried checking additional drivers, but the wi-fi driver doesn't show up.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for all the replies

P.s. My touchpad also doesn't work, but I'm more concerned with the wi-fi not working

Edit: After using `sudo ndisgtk` I get `Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without transient parent. This is discouraged.`

Edit2: thanks for the comments Ron here is what it says:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

Comment: sure it is the right driver?

Comment: Hey it looks lik I can't post pictures yet, but my PC tells me I'm using a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter. When I look at details I get: C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\netr28x.sys and C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vwifibus.sys and C:\Windows\system32\RaCoInst.dat and C:\Windows\system32\RaCoInst.dll

Comment: It also gives the version 5.00.46.0000 by Ralink Technology Corp, and the driver map I got and installed from Asus is called WLAN_Ralink_Win81_64_VER50460 so it should be the right version right?

Comment: what's the result of `lspci`?

Comment: Hey Ron I also found this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146/comments/125 but i'm not sure how to do all of the steps in the terminal

Comment: Please ask a new question for the touchpad problem.

Answer (score 1):

The process used to install the driver is:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git
git clone https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7630e.git
cd mt7630e
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt76xx
sudo depmod -a
```

It compiled for me perfectly on Ubuntu 15.04. I haven't the device so I can test no further.

Answer (score 0):

This seems outdated, with Ubuntu 15.10 this did not work as I was getting error in make
I followed this article http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796 and it worked perfectly

Download:

Download the driver from [here](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/archive/release.zip) (It's a modification of the original driver  for easy installation)

Install:

Now follow the instructions below:

1. extract the archive in your Downloads directory (or any other directory).
2. In terminal run:

`cd ~/Downloads/MT7630E-release`        (change the path if you extracted in another folder)

3. now run these commands one by one:

`sudo chmod +x install`

`sudo ./install`

It will prompt for your password. Put your password and wait to finish the installaion.

After installation has been completed the wifi will appear in the networkmanager and bluetooth will be available for use. The driver will load at startup automatically, so you don't need to load the driver every time you reboot.

Comment: this driver works but the wifi stops working after an hour or so, no idea why